# Accessing css, js and image in root folder laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Please Help.

I want to access css,js and images in root folder laravel.
in the root folder laravel i have folder themes.

for view not problem but when i'm accessing css,js and images. not working.

[image]

when i clicked link css. i'm getting not found

[image]

Hierarchy for themes

[image]

Comment: u can set  `ASSET_URL` in `env`

Answer (score 0):

the asset() helper will look for the required path at the  **public dir**

your themes path should be something like that
project-path/public/themes/..